# Is there a word that can describe the the condition of growing up a plant from soil after struggling with the environment

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe the conditions where a new born plant comes out penetrating the hard soil after its struggle to develop itself.

Comment: And you want to say all that in one word!??

Answer (score -1):

The best terms to describe this stage of plant growth would be [**sprouting** or **seedling emergence**](https://www.saps.org.uk/saps-associates/browse-q-and-a/649-does-how-deep-you-plant-seeds-affect-how-long-it-takes-them-to-sprout).